# c# DirectoryInfo,GetFiles

Tags: c#

I have the following code which works fine. What I am trying to do (in one shot) is to check if a directory exists, and, if so I would like to check if a file exists within the folder. It returns Y if it does or else it returns N:

```
string s = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\EXP_Reports\\36000").Exists
   ? new DirectoryInfo("C:\\EXP_Reports\\36000").GetFiles("EXP Report #36001.pdf")
       .Any() ? "Y" : "N"
   : "N";
```

I am wondering if the above code can be optimized further. Please note that I would like to do it in one statement.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do it in one statement, when so much less readable than splitting it up?

Comment: Hi Jon, I am using this in a linq where I have something like FileExist = ..... As such, I thought having it in one statement would be necessary.

Comment: If this is LINQ to Objects, you can just put the code *readably* in a method, and then call that method from the query.

Comment: When you say "optimized", do you really mean compacted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not simply use `File.Exists`.

```
bool q = File.Exists(@"C:\EXP_Reports\36000\EXP Report #36001.pdf");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

I've also changed the code to use a `bool` instead of a `string` containing Y or N.

Also, using a verbatim string literal `@"..."` reads better.

Answer (score 2):

Use

`System.IO.Directory.Exists("...");`

and

`System.IO.File.Exists("...");`

No need to instantiate anything.

If you only need to check file existence, you do not need to check if the directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use `string s = File.Exists("C:\\EXP_Reports\\36000\\EXP Report #36001.pdf") ? "Y" : "N";`?